# bones not importing in to unreal engine properly

Tags: export, rigging, bones, import, unreal-engine

Im trying to import/export my model into Unreal 4, but when it imports some bones collapse back into the spine bones. Has anyone experienced this problem and does anyone know how to fix it?

I've included my import/export setting for both blender and unreal.

[image: Import and Export Screenshot]

As well as an image of my model and the problem I am having (circled in red).

[image: Example of issue]

Comment: Please use latest version of Blender (2.74), there have been fixes in this area since 2.73…